# hooking to modify keyboard input

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, window, hook

I'm trying to write a DLL which intercepts keyboard input and modifies the scan/vkey codes prior to the values being presented to the process event loop. The simplified dll code (generated by VS 2010):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "hookdll.h"


#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

static const char *LogFileName = "c:/tmp/hook_report.txt";
#define LogOpen() \
{\
        freopen(LogFileName, "w", stdout); \
}
#define Log(fmt, ...)   if ( 1 )\
{\
        fprintf(stdout, "%s:%d " fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);  \
        fflush(stdout); \
}


static HHOOK HookHandle;

char*
DbHookToString(LPARAM lParam)
{
    static char tmp[128];
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* hs = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
            sprintf(tmp,
            "vkCode=0x%02X"
            ", scanCode=0x%02X"
            ", flags=0x%08X"
            ", time=%d"
            ", dwExtraInfo=0x%08X",
            hs->vkCode
            , hs->scanCode
            , hs->flags
            , hs->time
            , hs->dwExtraInfo);
    return tmp;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK
keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    // Checks whether params contain action about keystroke
    if(nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* hs = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        Log("IN:  %d: %s", wParam, DbHookToString(lParam));
        switch(hs->vkCode)
        {
            default:
                break;
            case 0x31:
                ++hs->vkCode;
                ++hs->scanCode;
                break;
            case 0x32:
                //--hs->vkCode;
                //--hs->scanCode;
                break;
        }
        Log("OUT: %d: %s\n", wParam, DbHookToString(lParam));
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(HookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ChookdllApp, CWinApp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


ChookdllApp::ChookdllApp()
{
}



ChookdllApp theApp;



BOOL ChookdllApp::InitInstance()
{
    LogOpen();

    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    if (!AfxSocketInit())
    {
        Log("AfxSocketInit failed");
        return FALSE;
    }

    HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyHandler, NULL, 0);
    if(HookHandle == NULL) 
    {
        Log("SetWindowsHookEx failed");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The app code, in skeleton form, is a C++ windows form app containing a single text box in a single form; problem is the input characters, specifically the number '1' key, are coming through unaltered even though the DLL is reporting in a log file that it is being modified. Help anyone?

> ...hookdll.cpp:84 IN:  256: vkCode=0x31, scanCode=0x02, flags=0x00000000, time=11326265, dwExtraInfo=0x00000000
>   ...\hookdll.cpp:100 OUT: 256: vkCode=0x32, scanCode=0x03, flags=0x00000000, time=11326265, dwExtraInfo=0x00000000
>
> ...\hookdll.cpp:84 IN:  257: vkCode=0x31, scanCode=0x02, flags=0x00000080, time=11326374, dwExtraInfo=0x00000000
>   ...\hookdll.cpp:100 OUT: 257: vkCode=0x32, scanCode=0x03, flags=0x00000080, time=11326374, dwExtraInfo=0x00000000

...snip..

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL = LoadLibrary("hookdll.dll");
    if ( hinstDLL == NULL )
    {
        volatile int err = GetLastError();
        err += 1;
    }
}
```

...snip...
Many thanks.

Comment: Side note: While it might be legal (I won't claim to know much about keyboard hooks) I'd flag your modification of the `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` pointed to by `lParam` in a code review. I think you could work around this issue if you made a local copy of the structure, modified that, and passed it to `CallNextHookEx`.

Comment: Excellent point regarding the flagged in a code review... my wrist is appropriately slapped. Thanks!

Comment: However I defined a local copy of the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT, memcpy'ed the arg value, modified the local copy, and sent the local copy to the next hook and still not working. The text box is still receiving the unaltered input characters. it seems like perhaps the keyboard event has already "entered" the event pipeline before my hook is called leaving the original event unmodified. that's my best guess; regardless, it leaves me without a solution/method to achieve my goal; that is to modify keyboard characters 'before' they are pulled by the apps event loop... must be a solution somewhere...